# Python Machine Learning - Training/Testing and apply prediction to new dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I have only done training and testing on a single data set splits.
I have a supervised learning problem: Data 1 Training/Testing and Data 2: No labels. I am using pandas data frame.

Data set 1: supervised

```
text        y_variable
apple       fruit
orange      fruit
celery      vegetable
mango       fruit
```

Data set 2: with no label

```
text        to_be_predicted
orange      ?
celery      ?
mango       ?
```

I am using scikit learn:

```
X = df['text']
y = df['y_variable']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
X, y, test_size=0.2
```

This splits the existing dataframe into training and testing. How to I train/test first Data set 1 and apply it to the second data set? Machine Learning.

Data set 2: with no label

```
text        to_be_predicted
orange      fruit
celery      vegetable
mango       fruit
```

Comment: Are you trying to train an supervised method and test as an unsupervised method?? 
+ Don't you have extra information about each item? For example.... Shape / Weight / Color....?? 
Your df has only 2 columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many scikit-learn supervised classifiers have the ability to `predict` with new data.

For example, check out the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html) for K nearest neighbors:

```
knn.predict(new_data) # will predict classes for new data
```

**UPDATE**

When you predict the classes, based on new data, you only need to specify the new `X`. Here's a longer version of the code to describe better:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make some example data
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples = 100, n_features = 2, 
                  centers = 2, random_state = 123)

# fit supervised KNN classifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(X, y) 

# create 50 new data points
# with the same number of features as the training set
new_data = np.random.randn(50, 2)

# predict new labels
new_labels = knn.predict(new_data)

# plot training clusters
plt.plot(X[y== 1, 0], 
         X[y==1,1], 
         "C1o", label = "training cluster 1")
plt.plot(X[y== 0, 0], 
         X[y==0,1], 
         "C0o", label = "training custer 2")

# plot predictions on new data
plt.plot(new_data[new_labels== 1, 0], 
         new_data[new_labels==1,1], 
         "ro", label = "new data assigned to cluster 1")
plt.plot(new_data[new_labels== 0, 0], 
         new_data[new_labels==0,1], 
         "bo", label = "new data assigned to cluster 2")
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Do I have to specify what y-variable column is?

Comment: You do not have to specify `y` when you predict on new data.  I've updated my code to give a better example.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do any training you need to convert the categorical features into numerical variables. Otherwise, no model can deal with these data.

To convert to numerical features you will need to use `OneHotEncoder`: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Next, since you have labels in the training set, you need supervised learning. 
More here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html